# WP sIFR > Headline is Gray, supposed to be white!

Tags: sifr

Not sure if someone already asked this but I've specified the color of my headline in the WP sIFR plugin settings and it still comes out gray. It's not specified in the CSS just to make sure.

Any thoughts? the site is danroseonline.com/rosewedding

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using 3-character hex-codes.  Try using 6-characters instead.

Comment: Good luck with the wedding planning... 14 months to plan?  I've only two months left till mine.

BTW: You're supposed to hit the chunky tick-mark to select correct answers when you've asked your own question - it all helps the karma go round.

Comment: Thanks! yeah, that huge, obvious check mark missed my radar somehow. Good luck with your wedding, and congrats!